# Can I host a SSAS Cube in AppHarbor?

Tags: ssas, appharbor

I am looking to deploy a SSAS cube to a platform as a service.  I am wondering if anyone has done this on AppHarbor?
In the end I want a web based pivot table.  The data will be updated often so "rebuilds" may be needed or re-population of the source data (which is in sql server)
Or do you have a better suggestion?

Thanks

-Ken